# Why can a Final dictionary not be used as a literal in TypedDict?

Tags: python, dictionary, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I am trying to accomplish the below (see [mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&gist=ba896d671d14442d8ce458bc4f4f01e7)):

```
from typing import TypedDict, Final

account_schema: Final = {"name": str, "email": str}

Account = TypedDict("Account", account_schema)
AccountPatch = TypedDict("AccountPatch", account_schema, total=False)
```

Idea is that I can have my schema specified in one place, with a version requiring all fields (`Account`, when inserting in database) and a version making all fields optional (`AccountPatch`, when updating a database).

From [PEP 586](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/#interactions-with-final):

> The `Final` qualifier serves as a shorthand for declaring that a
> variable is effectively `Literal`.

But `mypy` errors with:

```
error: TypedDict() expects a dictionary literal as the second argument
```

Why does `TypedDict` not allow a `Final` dictionary as its second argument?

For my core problem, is there anyway I can use the same schema for two `TypedDict`s (one with totality, one with no totality) without having to duplicate the schema?

Comment: Note that a `Literal` is not a literal. The former is a type, the latter is syntax.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Then, is my understanding right that `account_schema` is effectively `Literal`, but it is not "literal" by the definition `TypedDict`'s constructor operates by?

Comment: This is not about the runtime constructor of ``TypedDict``, but about the meaning of *static typing*. In the context where the error shown originates, there is no constructor involved – it is all done by a static analyser. These require a dictionary literal, as in ``{1: 2, 3: 4}``. That the ``Literal`` type happens to be named similarly does not matter; it is not what common type checkers can work with here.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Got you, thanks for clarifying. Now asking for more of an opinion instead of concrete answer, but given that I can't specify a dictionary literal ahead of time to de-duplicate the schema, do you think code generation would be the route here to take?

Comment: But you answered my question, so if you're willing to post an answer about literal vs `Literal` I'll accept it.

Comment: Related https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4128

Comment: In case anyone is interested the error is raised here https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/990b6a6f03ad82c10cb8edbe70508b943336f7f3/mypy/semanal_typeddict.py#L242-L244

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, it is not possible. See the issue raised on mypy's github: [TypedDict keys reuse?](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/990b6a6f03ad82c10cb8edbe70508b943336f7f3/mypy/semanal_typeddict.py#L242-L244). The error is raised [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/990b6a6f03ad82c10cb8edbe70508b943336f7f3/mypy/semanal_typeddict.py#L242-L244).

The only way to define your two TypeDict is by repeating the code

```
from typing import TypedDict

Account = TypedDict("Account", {"name": str, "email": str})
AccountPatch = TypedDict("AccountPatch", {"name": str, "email": str}, total=False)
```