# Make all keys in a typed dict not required

Tags: python, python-typing, typeddict

I have an existing TypedDict containing multiple entries:

```
from typing import TypedDict
class Params(TypedDict):
    param1:str
    param2:str
    param3:str
```

I want to create the exact same TypedDict but with all the keys being optional so that the user can specify only certain parameters. I know I can do something like:

```
class OptionalParams(TypedDict, total=False):
    param1:str
    param2:str
    param3:str
```

but the problem with this method is that I have to duplicate the code. Is there a way to inherit from Params by making the keys optional ? I tried to do

```
class OptionalParams(Params, total=False):
    pass
```

but the linter does not understand that the parameters are optional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you ask for is not possible - at least if you use mypy - as you can read in the comments of [Why can a Final dictionary not be used as a literal in TypedDict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66396842/why-can-a-final-dictionary-not-be-used-as-a-literal-in-typeddict) and on mypy's github: [TypedDict keys reuse?](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4128). Pycharm seems to have the same limitation, as tested in the two other "Failed attempts" answers to your question.

When trying to run this code:

```
from typing import TypeDict

params = {"a": str, "b": str}
Params = TypedDict("Params", params)
```

mypy will give `error: TypedDict() expects a dictionary literal as the second argument`, thrown [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/990b6a6f03ad82c10cb8edbe70508b943336f7f3/mypy/semanal_typeddict.py#L242-L244) in the source code.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this for the same set of fields. Quoting from [PEP 589](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#totality).

> The **totality** flag only applies to items defined in the body of the
> **TypedDict** definition. Inherited items won’t be affected, and instead
> use totality of the **TypedDict** type where they were defined. This makes
> it possible to have a combination of required and non-required keys in
> a single **TypedDict** type.

It's possible to construct [required and non required keys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict.__optional_keys__) with a single TypedDict type.

```
>>> class Point2D(TypedDict, total=False):
...     x: int
...     y: int
...
>>> class Point3D(Point2D):
...     z: int
...
>>> Point3D.__required_keys__ == frozenset({'z'})
True
>>> Point3D.__optional_keys__ == frozenset({'x', 'y'})
True
```

But you have same set of keys(`param1`, `param2`, `param3`) that needs to be **mandatory** and **optional**. Hence that has be inherited from `TypedDict` separately with `total=False`

```
class OptionalParams(TypedDict, total=False):
    param1:str
    param2:str
    param3:str
```